# How to add new cost function to neural network module?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, supervised-learning

Several days ago, I used the sklearn multilayer perceptron module for predictions.

Now I try to change the cost function while I using the neural network method which may make the prediction results more accurate. I have added the new cost function to ‘_base.py’ and also I have changed some codes in ‘multilayer_perceptron.py’. However, when I try to call the package and the module, there is a ‘no module named...’ problem. I tried several methods to solve this problem, like check the ‘*init*.py’ file and check the ‘PYTHONPATH’, but these methods don’t work.

So, could you please give me some guide on how to change the cost function? I would appreciate that and thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please have a look at: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to avoid asking questions that are to broad or lack necessary details in the future.

Comment: How have you installed the scikit-learn? Have you cloned the repo from github and making changes in that? Or you installed in editable mode?

Comment: @VivekKumar  I used the anaconda. now I clone a scikit-learn package from GitHub, and changed part of the package, but I did not install this package, I just want to call this package, does that work?

Comment: If  the part that you want to call does not depend on other parts of the scikit-learn, and does not depend on cython parts, that may work, but I'm not sure. You should install/compile the sklearn after changing, with an `-e` flag, so that you are able to change it later.